# Error compiling fragment shader on GLSL 1.30

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

what is wrong with the following fragment shader? It compiles OK under GLSL 4.0 but fails on GLSL 1.30.

This is the code:

```
// Fragment Shader
"uniform sampler2D texture;\n"
"uniform sampler1D cmap;\n"
"uniform float minZ;\n"
"uniform float maxZ;\n"
"\n"
"void main() {\n"
"    float height = texture2D(texture,gl_TexCoord[0].st);\n"
"    float lum = (height-minZ)/(maxZ-minZ);\n"
"    if (lum > 1.0) lum = 1.0;\n"
"    else if (lum < 0.0) lum = 0.0;\n"
"    gl_FragColor = texture1D(cmap, lum);\n"
"}"
```

These are the errors:

```
FRAGMENT glCompileShader "" FAILED
FRAGMENT Shader "" infolog:
0:7(2): error: initializer of type vec4 cannot be assigned to variable of type float
0:8(2): error: initializer of type vec4 cannot be assigned to variable of type float
0:9(6): error: operands to relational operators must be scalar and numeric
0:9(6): error: if-statement condition must be scalar boolean
0:9(17): error: value of type float cannot be assigned to variable of type vec4
0:10(11): error: operands to relational operators must be scalar and numeric
```

Comment: "*It compiles OK under GLSL 4.0 but fails on GLSL 3.0.*" There is no GLSL 3.0. There is a GLSL ***ES*** 3.00, but that's different.

Comment: There is no GLSL 3.5 *anywhere*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the error messages are very clear about what is wrong:

```
0:7(2): error: initializer of type vec4 cannot be assigned to variable of type float
----
float height = texture2D(texture,gl_TexCoord[0].st);
```

One cannot assign a vec4 to a float. texture2D returns a vec4, so it cannot be assigned to the float height.
Solution: Add a swizzle operator when you only need one channel:

```
float height = texture2D(texture,gl_TexCoord[0].st).r;
```

Beside this, the shader should not compile in any glsl version > 140, since `gl_TexCoord` was removed in 150. Same goes for the `texture2D` and `texture1D` method which got replaced by the `texture` function in 150. Are you really specifying the glsl version with `#version 400`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the version that you want to compile. As explained in [Core Language GLSL @ opengl.org](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_Language_%28GLSL%29):

> The #version​ directive must appear before anything else in a shader, save for whitespace and comments. If a #version​ directive does not appear at the top, then it assumes 1.10, which is almost certainly not what you want.